# How to divide the string into two divs?

Tags: php, string

I have one doubt in php,
suppose I have one string of 150 words, I want to display the first 80 words in one div and the remaining 70 words in another div.
can anyone help me with the code to acheive this.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Do you mean characters or words?

Comment: @CompuChip.. I mean words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like

```
<div ><?php echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $str), 0, 80));?></div>
<div ><?php echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $str), 81, 150));?></div>
```

Comment: That's characters. Maybe that's what the OP meant, but he said words.

Comment: @Gautam3164..thanks..but your answer suits for characters...but I want show from 0 to 80 words in one div and 80 to 150th word in another div..

Comment: what you are getting..?

Comment: probably getting `<div></div><div></div>` ... you missed the `echo` (or `<?=` shorthand) ;) ... once that's in it works perfectly.

Comment: @Gautam3164..Sorry Gautham..Now I am getting the output..Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question again, that's what I'd do :

```
    function splitByWords($string, $start = null, $end = null) {
        $words = explode(' ', $string);

        $newString = '';

        $end = $end === null ? count($words) : $end + 1;
        $start = $start === null ? 0 : $start;

        if(count($words) == 0 || count($words) < $start)
            return $string;

        for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
            if(array_key_exists($i, $words))
                $newString .=  strlen($newString) !== 0 ? ' ' . $words[$i] : $words[$i];

        return $newString;
    }

    $string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis rhoncus neque. Curabitur ultrices sem luctus interdum feugiat. Sed purus nulla, rhoncus nec diam sed, sodales semper felis. Aliquam ultrices feugiat venenatis. Maecenas eu rutrum nibh, sit amet ultrices quam. Duis justo arcu, bibendum ac velit vel, cursus accumsan erat. Duis scelerisque eget augue id consectetur. Aenean bibendum sapien vel nisl imperdiet convallis. Nam a nunc justo. Etiam porttitor euismod erat, eu volutpat lacus elementum ac. Mauris scelerisque blandit eros lacinia congue. Etiam fermentum risus quis turpis semper ultricies. Phasellus lacinia, lorem eget interdum condimentum, dolor nibh euismod augue, ut euismod diam orci non nulla.";

    $div1 = splitByWords($string, 9, 20);
    $div2 = splitByWords($string, 80);

    echo $div1;
```

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/kMYzhB)

[First method tried](https://ideone.com/hAti2v)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily with [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode), [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/array_slice) and [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode):

```
<?php
    function splitWords($string, $wordsPerEntry) {
        $words = explode(' ', $string);

        $return = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i += $wordsPerEntry) {
            $return[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, $i, $wordsPerEntry));
        }

        return $return;
    }
?>
```

**Usage**:

```
<?php
    $loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere ipsum sapien, eget consectetur felis placerat id. Suspendisse cursus eget nisi vitae aliquet. Mauris varius, metus eu feugiat mattis, magna arcu iaculis lorem, porttitor mollis ipsum justo at magna. Morbi at ligula iaculis, mollis lorem ac, bibendum purus. Mauris commodo porttitor magna. Morbi consequat ac ligula eu gravida. Cras tempus consectetur ipsum, nec convallis eros posuere ac. Aliquam luctus mi ac sapien scelerisque, et volutpat magna iaculis. Ut non risus tempor, aliquam felis et, placerat mi. Curabitur lacinia, nibh sed fermentum congue, velit velit tincidunt diam, sit amet scelerisque nisi leo at massa. Pellentesque porta mauris in turpis congue, convallis ornare mi porta. Vivamus semper iaculis sagittis. Etiam id nisi at sem rutrum aliquam. Duis tellus tellus, accumsan quis congue facilisis, ullamcorper quis leo. Donec commodo consectetur odio at porttitor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames.';

    $split = splitWords($loremIpsum, 80);

    print_r($split);

    foreach ($split as $line) {
        var_dump(count(explode(' ', $line)));
    }
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Array (
    [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere ipsum sapien, eget consectetur felis placerat id. Suspendisse cursus eget nisi vitae aliquet. Mauris varius, metus eu feugiat mattis, magna arcu iaculis lorem, porttitor mollis ipsum justo at magna. Morbi at ligula iaculis, mollis lorem ac, bibendum purus. Mauris commodo porttitor magna. Morbi consequat ac ligula eu gravida. Cras tempus consectetur ipsum, nec convallis eros posuere ac. Aliquam luctus mi ac sapien scelerisque, et volutpat magna iaculis. Ut non risus
    [1] => tempor, aliquam felis et, placerat mi. Curabitur lacinia, nibh sed fermentum congue, velit velit tincidunt diam, sit amet scelerisque nisi leo at massa. Pellentesque porta mauris in turpis congue, convallis ornare mi porta. Vivamus semper iaculis sagittis. Etiam id nisi at sem rutrum aliquam. Duis tellus tellus, accumsan quis congue facilisis, ullamcorper quis leo. Donec commodo consectetur odio at porttitor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. 
)    

int(80) //words in $split[0]
int(70) //words in $split[1]
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/06VTEJjh)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegExp with `{x,x}` repetition specify exactly 80 word matches and then exactly 70 word matches.

```
//string
$sStringOf150Words = " /* your string here */ ";

//pattern match
$reMatch = '/^((?:[^\s]+\s?){80})\s((?:[^\s]+\s?){70})$/';

//matches
$sFirst80Words = preg_replace($reMatch, "$1", $sStringOf150Words);
$sNext70Words = preg_replace($reMatch, "$2", $sStringOf150Words);

//output
echo "<div>{$sFirst80Words}</div>"
   . "<div>{$sNext70Words}</div>";
```